# Asp.Net Culture name without region/country name and default settings

Tags: asp.net, globalization, cultureinfo, culture, currentuiculture

I am working a multi-lang site. I want to get and set `culture` and `uiculture` with `culturename` without countryname. If browser is english or lang is English choosen, it will return `en` not `en-US` or `en-GB`. Because I use one localresources file per language and I have to send language code to sql procedure as a parameter.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

All of them returns en-GB,de-DE,de-AT etc... I just want first part and use this ones.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28VS.71%29.aspx
There are the name in the link but browser does note return it, I just want and use the simple part.
How can I do that?

It is solved (:

edit:
Now, How can I read browser's culture and if I don't have it, how can I set the culture that I have.
eg: I have `en`,`de`,`ru` and the visitor's browser sen me `fr`, I want it is shown en ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [TwoLetterISOLanguageName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.twoletterisolanguagename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-property. It should return the identifier you are looking for. For example:

```
var cult = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US").TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
```

Returns `"en"` so that you can send it to the stored procedures.

Comment: @user3318568: By default, the browser's culture should also be set in your application. If you want to set it in another way, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx.